# Find & replace url to HTML tag using regular expression

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, expression

I wish to have a function that I could parse in text and then it will replaces all the links that contain of (jpg|png|gif|jpeg|bmp) extension with `<img>` tag, after that it will also replaces all the other links without (jpg|png|gif|jpeg|bmp) extension with `<a>` tag.

For example it should replaces:

`http://imgur.com/gallery/TpGvHBL http://i.imgur.com/TpGvHBL.jpg`

to

`<a href="http://imgur.com/gallery/TpGvHBL" target="_blank">http://imgur.com/gallery/TpGvHBL</a> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TpGvHBL.jpg" />`

===========================================================================

Currently I'm able to replace image url to `<img>` tag using below regex:

`$text = preg_replace('#((https?|ftp):\/\/([^\s]*)\.(jpg|gif|png))#', '<img src="$1" />', $text);`

and also below to replace normal url to `<a>` tag:

`$text = preg_replace('/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);`

What I want is to change the second regex to replace non image url only, as it will conflicted with my first regex.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried ? Stackoverflow isn't some free-service to get ready-bakked code. Try something and I'll be glad to help. Hints: 1) Try to match url's with those extensions 2) Save those url's in an array 3) loop through that array, remove those extensions 4) Loop through the array(without extensions) and try to do some regex replace, use `\b` to prevent false matches 5) enjoy

Comment: Hi @HamZa, actually I'm searching for a solution which can directly replace all the url in the text instead of using array, however, I had updated with the codes that I had tried, please give me some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>Sorry for the late reply, I'm going to answer on the fly.</sub>

So here's the solution I came up with:

```
$string = 'some test http://imgur.com/gallery/TpGvHBL http://i.imgur.com/TpGvHBL.jpg something else ...';

$result = preg_replace_callback('~\b(?:https?|ftp|file)://\S+~i', function($v){
    if(preg_match('~\.jpe?g|\.png|\.gif|\.bmp$~i', $v[0])){ // if image
        return '<img src="' . $v[0] . '">';
    }else{
        return '<a href="' . $v[0] . '" target="_blank">' . $v[0] . '</a>';
    }
}, $string);
```

I thought of matching all url's and then check if there is an image extension. Of course the first regex is very loose and you might improve it ... Note that you need PHP 5.3+ since I'm using an anonymous function.

**Regex explanation:**

```
~                   # delimiter
    \b              # word boundary
    (?:             # start of a non-capturing group
        https?      # match http or https
        |           # or
        ftp         # match ftp (you may want to add sftp o_O ?)
        |           # or
        file        # match file
    )               # end of the non-capturing group
    ://             # match ://
    \S+             # match anything except whitespace one or more times
~                   # delimiter, end of expression
i                   # set the i modifier : match case-insensitive
```

The second regex `~\.jpe?g|\.png|\.gif|\.bmp$~i` just matches the following extensions `jpg, jpeg, png, gif and bmp` at the end of the string.

Comment: Lol I never know that there is a preg_replace_callback function, thanks for pointing it out, it works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

### Solution 1:

```
<?php
$str="http://imgur.com/gallery/TpGvHBL http://i.imgur.com/TpGvHBL.jpg";
$new_str=explode(" ",$str);
$str="<a href=".$new_str[0]." target=_blank>".$new_str[0]."</a>";
$str.=" <img src=".$new_str[1]." />";
echo htmlentities($str);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<a href=http://imgur.com/gallery/TpGvHBL target=_blank>http://imgur.com/gallery/TpGvHBL</a> <img src=http://i.imgur.com/TpGvHBL.jpg />
```

### Solution 2:

```
<?php
//$str='http://imgur.com/gallery/TpGvHBL';
$str='http://i.imgur.com/TpGvHBL.jpg';
if(is_array(getimagesize($str)))
{
echo "Image<br>";
    $str="<img src=".$str." />";
}
else
{
    echo "Link<br>";
    $str="<a href=".$str." target=_blank>".$str."</a>";
}
echo htmlentities($str);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Image
http://i.imgur.com/TpGvHBL.jpg
```

Comment: He was looking for an Regex ;)

Comment: Yea @demonking was right, I'm looking for regex to replace entire text's url, thanks for your reply anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

[@hamza's RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19618437/7404943) misses some symbols that cannot belong to URL, e.g. quotes, parentheses etc.

I would suggest to change this:

```
~\b(?:https?|ftp|file)://\S+~i
```

to this:

```
~\b(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/[^\s"'(){}<>|\\^~`]+~i
```

Comment: @bummi unfotunately it's my first answer here and i don't have enough reputation to put comments to other people's answers. I only can put new answers :(

Comment: Make it a standalone answer (mentioning hamza). As it stands it's a comment in the answer section and likely to be deleted.